# reorder array of Strings with minimal DB update operations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Lets say im storing some ordered strings like this:

```
   1 apple
   2 banana
   3 pear
   4 mango
   5 cantaloupe
```

Now I need to insert strawberry that should show up at position 4. 
OFC I can easily do that by updating numeric index, ex:

```
   1 apple
   2 banana
   3 pear
   4 strawberry
   5 mango
   6 cantaloupe
```

But the issue is - if I need to store this position update in the database I now need to store 3 operations:

```
   a) UPDATE index = 6, WHERE index=5  
   b) UPDATE index = 5, WHERE index=4  
   c) insert strawberry at position 4
```

Which is fine for small lists, but in large lists I would end up with a large number of position update operations.

Is there a more efficient approach?   Maybe using something other than numbers?

Comment: is `UPDATE index = (index + 1), WHERE index > 3`, before inserting strawberry in 4, an option ?

Comment: This question looks more specific to android than algorithm, should add android tag.

Comment: @SomeDude I've removed android reference - sorry only added it as an example

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi that is an option for sure I suppose. but I was wondering if there is some novel approach im missing here, perhaps using some GUIDs instead of indexes with some naming convention or something.

Comment: @ldv you can use GUIDs but you need a field to order those items, unless you can, via query, return the order you like, but that doesn't seem the case. So, even with GUIDs, you need a field with numbers, and databases in general are very fast and smart at doing many operations at once like the one I've suggested, instead of `O(n)` distinct UPDATEs.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by db (database) - is it an actual database managed by a dedicated database library, or a file, memory table, or other data structure (tree, perhaps), that you maintain yourself?

Comment: @Internal Server ok. it's an android app which stores sorted lists locally in sqlite (this part I have no issue with). Then this app needs to sync this data with remote mysql server using rest api. Im trying to find a most efficient way to implement sync operation. I suppose I might be overthinking it and simple  query like "UPDATE index = (index + 1), WHERE index > 3" works for me.